# Mutate to create mutilple new columns based on names of existing columns and presence of strings

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have three questions but they are related.

My starting point is [image: original table]

**Question 1:** I want to create five new columns: # Enterprises_Sig, Revenues_Sig, Costs_Sig, Net Revenues_Sig, and Assets_Sig. These columns would contain the identical number of * in their respective column. The original columns would then only contain the numbers. For example, the below code does what I need but only for one column.

```
table_2 <- table_2 %>% mutate("Net Revenues_Sig" = ifelse(str_count(table_2$`Net Revenues`,"∗")==1, "∗",ifelse(str_count(table_2$`Net Revenues`,"∗")==2, "∗∗",ifelse(str_count(table_2$`Net Revenues`,"∗")==3, "∗∗∗",""))))

table_2$`Net Revenues` <- str_replace_all(table_2$`Net Revenues`, "[∗]", "")
```

to produce [image]

Of course I could repeat this process another 4 times but there must be a more efficient way of doing this...?

**Question 2**: I want to do something similar but for the square brackets. How would I create 5 new columns for the respective standard errors without the brackets (e.g the new column Revenues_SE would be numeric and contain values 24346.05, 16080.92, 34895.03) and then remove those three rows (so Revenues only had the three long-term, short-term and lumpsum values)?

**Question 3**: How do I then convert all columns into numeric (currently character due to the brackets and asterisks) except for the 5 Sig columns ?

```
structure(list(Treatment = c("Long Term Arm", "", "Short Term Arm", 
"", "Lumpsum Arm", ""), `# Enterprises` = c("9.93∗∗", "[3.96]", 
"3.39", "[3.57]", "14.67∗∗∗", "[3.92]"), Revenues = c("61379.40∗∗", 
"[24346.05]", "23177.47", "[16080.92]", "107746.75∗∗∗", 
"[34895.03]"), Costs = c("32055.29∗", "[16478.13]", "8497.42", 
"[10462.44]", "71903.23∗∗∗", "[24360.84]"), `Net Revenues` =
c("28226.05∗∗",  "[12334.27]", "14824.71∗", "[8143.69]",
"35576.39∗∗∗",  "[13382.81]"), Assets = c("36050.66∗∗∗", "[12589.11]",
"16441.81", "[10029.27]", "29404.54∗∗∗", "[10977.68]")), row.names =
3:8, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you able to share an example of `table_2`?

Comment: Stefan, I'm not sure I understand, I'm still getting used to this platform. I added pictures of table_2, can you not see them?

Comment: Its better to share the code for an example dataframe rather than showing a picture of it on here. Running this would give you the code to be able to recreate the dataframe `dput(head(table_2))`

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I added it at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this does what you want. You'll need `library(data.table)` and `library(stringr)`.

```r
# structure
table_2 <- structure(
    list(
        Treatment = c("Long Term Arm", "", "Short Term Arm", "", "Lumpsum Arm", ""),
        `# Enterprises` = c("9.93∗∗", "[3.96]", "3.39", "[3.57]", "14.67∗∗∗", "[3.92]"),
        Revenues = c("61379.40∗∗", "[24346.05]", "23177.47", "[16080.92]", "107746.75∗∗∗", "[34895.03]"),
        Costs = c("32055.29∗", "[16478.13]", "8497.42", "[10462.44]", "71903.23∗∗∗", "[24360.84]"),
        `Net Revenues` = c("28226.05∗∗", "[12334.27]", "14824.71∗", "[8143.69]", "35576.39∗∗∗", "[13382.81]"),
        Assets = c("36050.66∗∗∗", "[12589.11]", "16441.81", "[10029.27]", "29404.54∗∗∗", "[10977.68]")
    ),
    row.names = 3:8, class = "data.frame"
)

# turn to dt
table_2 <- data.table::as.data.table(table_2)

# redo treatment
trt <- table_2$Treatment
for (i in seq_len(length(trt))) {
    t <- trt[i]
    if (t == "") {
        trt[i] <- paste0(trt[i - 1], " SE")
        trt[i] <- trt[i - 1]
    }
}
table_2[, Treatment := trt]

# get columns to change
to_change <- colnames(table_2)[colnames(table_2) != "Treatment"]

# add on Sig to each column
to_change_sig <- paste0(to_change, " Sig")

# first function - extract all ∗ and collapse
fun <- function(y) {
    z <- stringr::str_extract_all(y, "∗")
    lapply(z, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "")) |> unlist()
}

# extracts the stars
table_2[, (to_change_sig) := lapply(.SD, fun), .SDcols = to_change]

# melt down
table_2 <- data.table::melt(table_2, id.vars = "Treatment")
table_2[, grp := ifelse(stringr::str_detect(value, "\\["), "SE", "Estimate")]
table_2[variable %in% to_change_sig, grp := "Sig"]

# functino to remove all brackets and stars, turn to numeric
fun <- function(y) {
    z <- stringr::str_remove_all(y, "\\[|\\]|∗")
    as.numeric(z)
}

# apply it only to estimate and se
table_2[grp != "Sig", value := fun(value)]

# remove " Sig" from the significance variables (for casting wide)
table_2[, variable := stringr::str_remove_all(variable, " Sig")]

# order the table (like dplyr::arrange)
data.table::setorder(table_2, Treatment, variable, grp)

# remove values where there are no stars
table_2 <- table_2[value != ""]

# cast wide
table_2 <- data.table::dcast(
    table_2,
    Treatment + variable ~ grp,
    value.var = "value"
)
```

```
r$> table_2
Key: <Treatment, variable>
         Treatment      variable  Estimate       SE    Sig
            <char>        <char>    <char>   <char> <char>
 1:  Long Term Arm # Enterprises      9.93     3.96     ∗∗
 2:  Long Term Arm        Assets  36050.66 12589.11    ∗∗∗
 3:  Long Term Arm         Costs  32055.29 16478.13      ∗
 4:  Long Term Arm  Net Revenues  28226.05 12334.27     ∗∗
 5:  Long Term Arm      Revenues   61379.4 24346.05     ∗∗
 6:    Lumpsum Arm # Enterprises     14.67     3.92    ∗∗∗
 7:    Lumpsum Arm        Assets  29404.54 10977.68    ∗∗∗
 8:    Lumpsum Arm         Costs  71903.23 24360.84    ∗∗∗
 9:    Lumpsum Arm  Net Revenues  35576.39 13382.81    ∗∗∗
10:    Lumpsum Arm      Revenues 107746.75 34895.03    ∗∗∗
11: Short Term Arm # Enterprises      3.39     3.57   <NA>
12: Short Term Arm        Assets  16441.81 10029.27   <NA>
13: Short Term Arm         Costs   8497.42 10462.44   <NA>
14: Short Term Arm  Net Revenues  14824.71  8143.69      ∗
15: Short Term Arm      Revenues  23177.47 16080.92   <NA>
```

It looks like you're dealing with some kind of model output turned into a data.frame - if that's true you might want to see if you can just extract the same information directly from the model instead of this approach.

Anyway, hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**

I didn't see part 2 of the question above where you also want to add SE columns. The solution now does this.

Explanation:

In order to add SE columns, we need to fill in the appropriate Treatment since they are blank. That is what these lines do:

```r
# redo treatment
trt <- table_2$Treatment
for (i in seq_len(length(trt))) {
    t <- trt[i]
    if (t == "") {
        trt[i] <- paste0(trt[i - 1], " SE")
        trt[i] <- trt[i - 1]
    }
}
table_2[, Treatment := trt]
```

```
r$> table_2$Treatment
[1] "Long Term Arm"  "Long Term Arm"  "Short Term Arm"
[4] "Short Term Arm" "Lumpsum Arm"    "Lumpsum Arm"
```

To extract the stars, I use

```r
# first function - extract all ∗ and collapse
fun <- function(y) {
    z <- stringr::str_extract_all(y, "∗")
    lapply(z, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "")) |> unlist()
}
```

The reason this looks complicated is that str_extract_all returns a list. If we set

```r
y <- x$Costs
```

```r
r$> stringr::str_extract_all(y, "∗")
[[1]]
[1] "∗"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
character(0)

[[5]]
[1] "∗" "∗" "∗"

[[6]]
character(0)
```

You can see how in element 5, the stars are not together and instead are like a vector. Think `c("*", "*", "*")` as opposed to `"***"`. That is where the `collapse` argument in `paste0` comes into play:

```r
r$> lapply(z, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ""))
[[1]]
[1] "∗"

[[2]]
[1] ""

[[3]]
[1] ""

[[4]]
[1] ""

[[5]]
[1] "∗∗∗"

[[6]]
[1] ""
```

Then, we just need to unlist so we can put it back into the data.frame.

As for

```r
# first function - extract all ∗ and collapse
fun <- function(y) {
    z <- stringr::str_extract_all(y, "∗")
    lapply(z, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "")) |> unlist()
}

# extracts the stars
table_2[, (to_change_sig) := lapply(.SD, fun), .SDcols = to_change]
```

This is some of the more confusing `data.table` syntax but basically we defined `to_change_sig` as your column names with " Sig" at the end of it. If we did

```r
table_2[, (to_change_sig) := 1]
```

It would create all of those columns with 1's in them:

```r
r$> head(table_2)
        Treatment # Enterprises     Revenues       Costs Net Revenues      Assets
           <char>        <char>       <char>      <char>       <char>      <char>
1:  Long Term Arm        9.93∗∗   61379.40∗∗   32055.29∗   28226.05∗∗ 36050.66∗∗∗
2:  Long Term Arm        [3.96]   [24346.05]  [16478.13]   [12334.27]  [12589.11]
3: Short Term Arm          3.39     23177.47     8497.42    14824.71∗    16441.81
4: Short Term Arm        [3.57]   [16080.92]  [10462.44]    [8143.69]  [10029.27]
5:    Lumpsum Arm      14.67∗∗∗ 107746.75∗∗∗ 71903.23∗∗∗  35576.39∗∗∗ 29404.54∗∗∗
6:    Lumpsum Arm        [3.92]   [34895.03]  [24360.84]   [13382.81]  [10977.68]
   # Enterprises Sig Revenues Sig Costs Sig Net Revenues Sig Assets Sig
              <char>       <char>    <char>           <char>     <char>
1:                 1            1         1                1          1
2:                 1            1         1                1          1
3:                 1            1         1                1          1
4:                 1            1         1                1          1
5:                 1            1         1                1          1
6:                 1            1         1                1          1
```

So that's the first part. What `:= lapply(.SD, fun), .SDcols = to_change` does is say "apply the function `fun` across the columns in `.SDcols`". So, we create the columns in `to_change_sig` by applying `fun` to each of the original columns that we specified in `to_change`. You can probably imagine here that ordering of `to_change` MUST align with `to_change_sig`.

Since you also want SE's as a separate column, the best way I could think to do this was to melt and cast wide again. Hence the update.

Comment: This looks great thank you, but I'm having trouble following and understanding the solution. If I want to keep the table to still be called table_2, which xs do I leave as x and which do I change to table_2? Also, can you please explain these 2 lines as I don't yet understand how they work:     lapply(z, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "")) |> unlist()
}
x[, (to_change_sig) := lapply(.SD, fun), .SDcols = to_change]

Comment: Hi there, I realized I didn't answer your second question on how to add SE columns so I edited in a way that makes most sense to me and added some info on the paste0 thing. Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: I really appreciate all your detailed help. I can't get the solution to work now though. After trt <- table_2$Treatment
for (i in seq_len(length(trt))) {
    t <- trt[i]
    if (t == "") {
        trt[i] <- paste0(trt[i - 1], " SE")
        trt[i] <- trt[i - 1]
    }
}
table_2[, Treatment := trt], I get the error: Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(table_2, , `:=`(Treatment, trt)) :
  Column 'Treatment' does not exist to remove

Comment: Hi there, did you make sure you turned table_2 into a data.table with `table_2 <- data.table::as.data.table(table_2)`? `table_2[, Treatment := trt]` will only work if it is. You might also want to try restarting R and running from the beginning

Comment: You were right, restarting R fixed it. This is all incredibly helpful, thank you so much for the explanation - you solved my problem and taught me a LOT in the process. A couple of final questions: (1) Why include the line trt[i] <- paste0(trt[i - 1], " SE") in the forloop if we get the same result without it? (2) What does "r$>" do?

Comment: Happy to help! :) You're totally right about pasting SE at the end - that was leftover from when I was trying to figure it out haha. `r$>` is just the radian console - I use VS Code w/ radian as the terminal more about that here: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2019/06/18/radian-console-for-r/.